# Training MTCNN For Face Detection

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, face-detection

I am working on face detection. I am referring paper Joint Face Detection and Alignment using
Multi-task Cascaded Convolutional Networks. So they mentioned they are using positive images, negative images , part images and landmark images for training.

Negatives and positives are used for face classification tasks,
positives and part faces are used for bounding box regression,
and landmark faces are used for facial landmark localization.

They randomly crop several patches from WIDER
FACE to collect positives, negatives and part face. Then,
they crop faces from CelebA as landmark faces.

So my question is for landmark face from CelebA we have 5 landmarks but the positive and part faces from WIDER FACE we didn't have landmark so at training time how we can define the ground truth for this?